# Power Automate: Take one email with two attachments and save each attachment into a different folder

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, onedrive, power-automate

I used to get an email with *one* attachment and save it to a sharepoint/onedrive folder through Power Automate. The condition was that it had an attachment, then part of the subject and the sender email address. However, now I get two attachments in the same email, with different attachment names (the vendor will not send these separately). Now I have been trying multiple ways of moving these two attachments into separate sharepoint/onedrive folders.. without success.

What I have now (trying to check what the name of the attachment is, and based on that, move it to a specific folder). The difference between this and what I had when there was only one attachment, is the "Get Attachment (V2)" step and the Condition. However, when I try to run it, the first and second condition returns "false".. although the name does contain exactly what I have written as the condition..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to have the condition in a "apply to each attachment in email" (apply to each) step, and then just wait for the actual email I am setting this up for to arrive. My testing failed due to my own email being digitally signed / encrypted, which Power Automate cannot handle..